# How to print a custom region in a custom module's template?

Tags: 7, theming

I want to define a region, but the problem is that for different pages, the position of the region would be slightly different. So I can not put the region in `page.tpl.php` and for different custom modules that I have created, I need to put it inside different places depending on the module. So far I have defined the region inside my custom theme, and I have tested the region inside `page.tpl.php` with a custom block and it works fine there. But when I put the code to print the region inside the custom module's template, nothing shows up.

The following code works in `page.tpl.php` but not in custom module's templates:

```
<?php print render($page['sidebar_ads']); ?>
```

#### Question

How do I pass the the `$page` variable to a custom modules template?

Comment: To what template exactly you need the region to be passed on?

Answer (score 1):

I am not getting exactly. but your position for other pages are different and different for the front page. why not you make two file

```
page--front.tpl.php
page.tpl.php.
```

You don't need to be worry about region. because region only enable if any block assign in that region!

Comment: The content of those pages that I'm talking about are so custom, that they don't have anything to do with page--front or nodes or anything else. Thanks for the answer anyways.

Comment: @Milad.Nozari – With what do they have to do then? At least an URL or anything unique, no? Then you need to add a custom template suggestion to look for `page--myurl.tpl.php` or any other custom marker and adjust these templates to print your regions in a different order.

Answer (score 0):

I use the Context module to use areas in different places based on conditions like which content type, view display, or even a specific node id, among other options. So you can specify several regions but instead of using a block in them automatically, allow Context to decide which types of pages will use which block in which region. This should allow for the dynamic display you are looking for in an easy-to-use module interface.